# Mysql insert. Can´t use multiple character value

Tags: python, mysql-python

If I try to insert a multiple character value like "12" into my database, it wont work.
Error_message:
    `Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared Statement`

If I try to insert a single character value like "9" into my database, it works.

Where is my error?

Things I tried:
I set the variable to a permanent value at different positions of the code.

The result was, that it only works for values greater than 9, if this value is a static in the query.

e.g.:
    `query = """insert into Sklaven (Adresse) values(12)"""
    result = cursor.execute(query)`

If I do it dynamic it wont work.
e.g.:
    `query = """insert into Sklaven (Adresse) values(%s)"""
    result = cursor.execute(query, Wert)`
or
    `result = cursor.execute(query, "12")`

Whole code:

```
Import mysql.connector

def insert_Value(Adressen):
  try:
    connection = mysql.connection.connect(host= '*.*.*.*', 
               database ='*',
               user = '*',
               Password ='*')
    Cursor = Connection.cursor(prepared=True)
    query = """insert into Sklaven (Adresse) values(%s)"""
    Wert = Adressen
    print ("Value = ", Wert)          #showing current value
    print ("len = ", len(Wert))       #showing lenght of current value
    result = cursor.execute(query, Wert)
    print("ok")
    connection.commit()
  expect mysql.connector.Error as error:
    connection.rollback()
    print("not ok {}".format(error))

S=8

for x in range(0,7):
  S = str(S)
  inserr_Value(S)
  S=int(S)
  S=S+1
```

Shell Returns:

```
value = 8
len = 1
ok
value = 9
len = 1
ok
value = 10
len = 2
not ok 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared Statement
value = 11
len = 2
not ok 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared Statement
value = 12
len = 2
not ok 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared Statement
value = 13
len = 2
not ok 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared Statement
value = 14
len = 2
not ok 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared Statement
```

Comment: Where is `insert_tuple` defined? I only see it used, in the query, but nowhere defined.

Comment: `result = cursor.execute(query, "12")`: use an actual tuple there (as per your non-working example code): `result = cursor.execute(query, (12,))`. Let us know if and how that works (note: if 12 is supposed to be a number, just leave off the quotes).

Comment: What is the column type of `Adresse`? An integer, a string, something else?

Comment: To insert values existents in a list, you can to use a loop. ```for item in list: query_to_insert(item)```

Comment: Oh sorry. Of course it should be `result = cursor.execute(query, Wert)`, instead of `result = cursor.execute(query, insert_tuple)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing

```
tuple_result = tuple(Wert)
```

just before the actual query, by any chance?

Try `tuple("12")` on the Python command line, then you'll see what the problem is: it comes out as `('1', '2')`. Strings, on such occasions, are often seen as a list of characters (or unicode code-points, if you like) for many operations.

Instead, you should construct your tuple simply as

```
tuple_result = (Wert,)
```

followed by

```
result = cursor.execute(query, insert_tuple)
```

(you could even use `tuple_result = Wert,`, but I wouldn't do that, for reasons of clarity).

Comment: Changing: `Wert = Adressen` to `Wert =(Adressen,)` has solved my Problem. Thank you very much.